# EM wave emission from earphone wires due to varying current signal

Tags: electromagnetism, acoustics, electronics, electrical-engineering, antennas

if we listen to some audio signal on a wired earphone, then does the wire of the earphone act as a transmitter antenna to emit the audio signal as radio waves even though its strength might be negligible?

Comment: Yes, the wire will function as an antenna. Since your earphone/headphone cable is much much shorter than the low frequency rf (<20 kHz) wavelength that it is radiating, the wire is a very poor radiator.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It's a *very* inefficient antenna. You'll never detect a radiated field even though *in theory* it's present.

Answer (score 1):

It will radiate as Joe Doty points out unless the wire is *shielded*, with the neutral return line wrapped around the hot (signal) line and a thin layer of insulation between. Shielded lines at audio frequencies are almost immune to radiation and similarly will pick up much less radiated interference from nearby sources.

Comment: Even shielded lines leak radiation. Adding a shield makes the wire even less efficient as an antenna, but it's not perfect.

Comment: @JohnDoty, will edit. -NN